# How to extract substring (path to folder) from string using batch script or PowerShell

Tags: string, cmd, escaping

I have been trying to remove in batch script "=" character from string by using this:

```
set Path_var=%Path_var:^==%
```

Unfortunately this does not work... I tried also some other common solutions like:

```
set Path_var=%Path_var:"="=%
set Path_var=%Path_var:'='=%
```

But without success. Maybe it would be worthy also to explain for what I need it as I am aware you may be able to provide better solution. I extract one line from xml configuration file. The line is following:

```
  <burning addDicomViewer="true" finalizeMedium="true" dicomViewer="C:\user\App_folder\App-name_subfolder_1.1.1_Setup" burnVerification="true" numberOfCopies="0" cleanupProjectData="false" volumeName="Patient Medium"/>
```

I need to extract from this line this path: **"C:\user\App_folder\App-name_subfolder_1.1.1_Setup"** (The path will not always be the same)

My strategy was to simply remove definite number of characters before the path as I know this setting will always be the same and therefore the length of the string won`t change.

```
set /p Path_var= < temp_file01.txt
set Path_var=%Path_var:~81,100%
```

Then I wanted to use simply substitution to remove the rest. For example:

```
set Path_var=%Path_var:burnVerification=%
```

But I ran into problem that my string contains characters like "=" which I can not remove by this method. (Because obviously there are handled as operators) What I was also wondering is what I should do if there will be a space character in my path. Then when I attempt to remove the empty characters at the end I also invalidate my path.

I know batch scripts are not the best for manipulation with strings, but I do not have other choice as my boss want me to use scripting language which does not need compiling.

Comment: You cannot in a single replacement like this. You need another way. for instance using a `for` loop to split it for you. `for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ("%path_var%") do echo %%i` where the first token would be the variable name, second the value. Here we only used token 2 (value)

Comment: but now that we have that covered. `batch-file`/`cmd` is a very bad idea to use here. There are too many special characters which is poisonous to cmd, so you have to hack a massive script to achieve something simple. I would recommend using `powershell` for this task.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it tomorrow and come back.

Comment: I have tried it, but unfortunately it does not work for me. I never get expected result as I guess these special characters change the behavior... You mentioned that in Powershell it is easier. Could you please write short powershell script which reads the whole line "<burning addDicomViewer......"Patient Medium"/>" from txt File extract only the path and inserts it in another txt file? Like this I could call from my batch script powershell script and then pick the result from another file.

Comment: And I also wanted to mention that the string left to the path will also change at times and therefore I can not cut it using definite length. (set Path_var=%Path_var:~81,100%) Also the only way how to narrow search for the substring is by looking for the beginning "C:\user" and then read all which follows till the next quotation mark.

Answer (score 1):

I asked my work colleague for help and he came with following PowerShell solution:

```
$path_temp_file01 = "C:\user\temp\tmpFile_backup_script01.txt"
$path_temp_file02 = "C:\user\temp\tmpFile_backup_script02.txt"
$string = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($path_temp_file01)
$Start = $string.IndexOf("C:")
$string = $string.substring($Start)
$End =$string.IndexOf("""")
$string = $string.substring(0,$End)
$string > $path_temp_file02
```

It works for me. I post it here in the case someone needs similar solution or has better idea how to do that.